# How do I fix this error

Tags: php

I am having trouble with my website. I'm fairly new to wordpress so I could use any help I can get:

PHP Notice: Undefined index: ics_add_slidelink_2_meta_box_nonce in /inc/slider/slider_post_type.php

Answer (score 0):

That looks like an error in a plugin called "Slider". You can test by disabling that plugin and seeing if the error re-occurs.

Note that this is not the place for plugin error/support. You should use the plugin's support forum.